# "EXCEPTION: Unexpected directive value 'undefined' on the View of component" in nested components

Tags: angular

I have two AngularJS 2.0 components:

**Comment** :

```
import {Component, Injectable, View, Input} from 'angular2/core';
import {Comments} from './comments.component';

@Injectable()

@Component({
    selector: 'comment'
})

@View({
    templateUrl: 'res/templates/components/comment.component.html',
    directives: [Comments]
})

export class Comment {
    @Input() comment;
    @Input() commentable = false;
}
```

**Comments** :

```
import {Component, Injectable, View, Input} from 'angular2/core';
import {CommentsService} from './../services/comments.service';
import {RouteParams} from 'angular2/router';
import {Comment} from './Comment.component';

@Injectable()

@Component({
    selector: 'comments',
    providers: [CommentsService]
})

@View({
    templateUrl: 'res/templates/components/comments.component.html',
    directives: [Comment]
})

export class Comments {
    @Input() ID;
    public comments;
    public commentsService: CommentsService;
    public routeParams: RouteParams;

    constructor (routeParams: RouteParams, commentsService: CommentsService) {
        var self = this;

        self.routeParams = routeParams;
        self.commentsService = commentsService;
    }

    ngOnInit()   {
        var self = this;

        if (self.ID !== undefined)
            self.comments = self.commentsService.comments[self.ID];
        else if (self.routeParams.params['id'] !== undefined)
            self.comments = self.commentsService.comments[self.routeParams.params['id']];
        else
            self.comments = undefined;
    }
}
```

**comment.template** :

```
<div class="post">
    <div class="author-pic"></div>
    <div class="body">
        <h2 class="title">{{comment.author.name}} {{comment.author.surname}}</h2>
        <h3 class="title">{{comment.publication | date:"MM/dd/yy"}}</h3>
        <p>{{comment.body}}</p>
    </div>
    <comments *ngIf="commentable" [ID]="comment.ID"></comments>
</div>
```

**comments.template** :

```
<div *ngIf="comments !== undefined">
    <comment *ngFor="#comment of comments" [comment]="comment" [commentable]="true"></commento>
</div>
```

In Comments' template I have an Angular Loop that prints multiple Comment components. In Comment's template I have an Angular ngIf that, if var commentable is true, prints a Comments component. When I run it I get:

```
EXCEPTION: Unexpected directive value 'undefined' on the View of component 'Comment'
```

Comment: Could you post the associated templates, and service(s) ? Why did you add the ***@Injectable*** decorator above components ?

Comment: Most likely because you have a circular dependency. Comments has Comment as directives and Comment has Comments as directives as well. Remove one of those from the other one.

Comment: If I remove one of those it wouldn't work... @Eric Martinez

Comment: How do you know it wouldn't work if it's not even working right now with that approach? Why do you need that circular dependency? If you want to get `Comments` from `Comment` (parent-child communication) you can just inject it, you don't need to add it as a directive.

Comment: I posted associated templates @Romain.

Comment: You don't need to store ***this*** in the ***self*** variable, it's useless and make your code less readable. I think that the problem may come from the fact that in the ***comments.template*** file you use the ***comment*** keyword for the element of your *ngFor and also for the input decorator, it may confused Angular, try to change one of them and tell us if it change something.

Comment: Thanks @Romain,  but nothing changes.

Answer (score 18):

There is a way to solve the circular dependency problem.

```
import {forwardRef} from 'angular2/core';
import {Comment} from './Comment.component';

...
directives: [forwardRef(() => Comment)]
})
```

I have tried this with `2.0.0-beta.10` and it works fine. See comment by tlancina in [this issue report](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/issues/5666) on github for more information.

Comment: While avoiding the circular dependency seems the more prudent approach, I have found this command extremely useful during development.

Answer (score 12):

A circular *TypeScript* import dependency can cause this. (I just ran into this)

For me:

1. **A** is the parent component, and `import`s and `export`s **B**, **C**, **D**. for convenience.
2. **A** tries to render **B**
3. **B** imports **C** *from* **A** and tries to render **C**.

As soon as I add **C** to the `directives` block of **B**, I get that error (whether it is in **B**'s template or not.) Really, since **A** depends on **B**, the minute I import anything from **A** into **B**'s block I get

> Unexpected directive value 'undefined'

@Eirc Martinez is right and you'll have to find a way around that circular dependency.

Comment: googling the error leads to this post, and finding/removed circular dependency solves it, thanks

Answer (score 6):

I often get this error when I've imported something that doesn't exist. Usually this means there's a misspelling in my import or something of the same nature.

For instance I get this error when I try to import:

```
import {Comment} from './Comment.component';
```

When I actually mean:

```
import {CommentComponent} from './Comment.component';
```

Answer (score 1):

I got a problem something like that. Although this is case sensitive problem. Finally solve this.

courses.component.ts

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core'

@Component({
selector: 'courses',
template: '<h2>Courses</h2>'
})

export class coursesComponent{

}
```

The mistake is coursesCompomnent class should be CoursesCompomnent. Just C is capital letter.

app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from 'angular2/core';
import{CoursesComponent} from './courses.component';

@Component({
selector: 'my-app',
template: '<h1>Hello Angular</h1><courses></courses>',
directives: [CoursesComponent]
})
export class AppComponent { 

}
```

https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/7526