# Nested tree view of component angular2

Tags: angular

Is there a way to render component in tree hierarchy..Dynamically..!
and looking for a result something like below..!

```
<component-selector>
    <component-selector>
          <component-selector></component-selector>
    </component-selector>
</component-selector>
```

Where  is selector-id, which has its own template,
If this is possible, can we bind model also according to the tree depth..!?

help me find solution..!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37746516/use-component-in-itself/37747022#37747022

Comment: @Günter Zöchbauer will this <ul>
    <li *ngFor="let node of node.children">
      <tree-node  [node]="node"></tree-node>
    </li>
  </ul> workout, it looks recursive..!

Comment: Is this good or bad? :D

Comment: yes it looks promising, leme try on it, and has different requirement, have to see if it fits..!

Comment: can you please take a look at these.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40040496/if-modelkey-condition-matches-set-a-specific-template-in-angular2