# if model[key] condition matches set a specific template in angular2

Tags: angular

Is there any way to get template rendered with data bound on angular2.
eg:
**Model** :

```
{
    "level0": {
      "level0-child0": "Value",
      "level0-child1": "valuecheck",
      "level1": {
        "level1-child0": "check"
      }
    }
  }
```

from this model, if "*level0-child0*" is === Value, I want to display the **template** in ***ImageComponent***.
similarly, if *level0-child1* === valuecheck, I want to display the **template** in **ImageOneComponent**.
Is there an option of dynamically build template from **Component-class**!

 
*What I have tried is*: Have acheived a recursive call to each keys in JSON.. But I am looped with in searching for *DynamicCompoentResolver*
Where Image/ImageOneComponent are, two different components, with templates, `<img src="image1"/>, <img src="image2"/>` respectively

Comment: What template? What `ImageComponent`. Please add more code. If you don't know what component statically, you can use something like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36325212/angular-2-dynamic-tabs-with-user-click-chosen-components/36325468#36325468

Comment: Similar to that answer, but it seems in ng2 stable "ComponentResolver" is no more available..! by the way I need to combine the previous tree with this loading, if you look into the json, it is hierarchical.

Comment: That answer already uses the `ComponentFactoryResolver` instead of the removed `ComponentResolver`.

Comment: @Gunter, tried changing the template to an <input> and tried to bind model, it throws exceptions, is there a way to acheive data binding too on the aboce answer?

Comment: "throws exception" isn't very helpful. What exception? What code causes the exception?

Comment: the exception is , [ngModel] , ngModel, (ngModel) etc are not valid format for 'input' tag is the exception.

Comment: Can you please copy-past the exact and full error message? Perhaps you are missing the `BrowserModule` (`AppModule` only) or `CommonModule` (for all other modules) in `@NgModule({ imports: [CommonModule]})`

Comment: Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'ngModel' since it isn't a known property of 'input'. ("<input type="text" [ERROR ->][(ngModel)]="type"/>")

Comment: Above error appears, when we change any template in any component to "<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="type"/>", in the plunk http://plnkr.co/edit/UGzoPTCHlXKWrn4p8gd1?p=preview

Comment: The Plunker is empty. Can you please check again?

Comment: Check now,I have edited and it is the same plunker that you have fiven in the answer..

Comment: How can I reproduce the exception?

Comment: Reproducing it will be, just change the template of a component from <h>C1</h> to <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="type"/>, it will throw exception

Comment: You need to add the `FormsModule` to `imports: []` of `@NgModule()` for `ngModel` to work. I also had to add a call to `detectChanges()` to work around another exception http://plnkr.co/edit/UGzoPTCHlXKWrn4p8gd1?p=preview

Comment: Okay, thats a great turing point.. leme try on that...!