# Angular 2: Recursive template for child

Tags: angular, ngfor

The API I am working against gives me the following structure in response:

```
"data": [
{
  "id": 5,
  "name": "First name",
  "parent": 0
},
{
  "id": 1,
  "name": "Second name",
  "parent": 5
},
{
  "id": 6,
  "name": "Third name",
  "parent": 1
},
{
  "id": 15,
  "name": "Fourth name",
  "parent": 0
},
{
  "id": 25,
  "name": "Fifth name",
  "parent": 5
}
]
```

I would like to build a tree structure around this using `ngFor` that supports an unlimited number of children levels.

This is what I have tried so far:

```
<div *ngFor="let d1 of _dataList">
<ul *ngIf="d1.parent == 0">
    <li>
        {{d1.name}}
        <ul *ngFor="let d2 of _dataList">
            <li *ngIf="d2.parent == d1.id">{{d2.name}}</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
</div>
```

That works, but it's ugly and I have to manually repeat this X-levels down the data and thus leaving a hard-coded limit.

How can one optimize this code to support unlimited levels - and look better?

Comment: This might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37746516/use-component-in-itself-recursively-to-create-a-tree/37747022#37747022

Comment: I would rather say it's a duplicate

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Use component in itself recursively to create a tree](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37746516/use-component-in-itself-recursively-to-create-a-tree)

Comment: You'll want to format your data and use a recursive structure like the question linked above. You should probably format it so every node that has children has them in an array, and then you can pass data around more easily recursively.

Comment: Thanks Seiyria, I'll look into the possibility of having the API return the list in a different format.

Answer (score 4):

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-yij5e5?file=src%2Fapp%2Ftree-view%2Ftree-view.component.ts
Note: below code is not recursive it is 2d and can't use for tree render.
you should use ng template or defining a component for it.

```
<div *ngFor="let d1 of _dataList">
<ul *ngIf="d1.parent == 0">
    <li>
        {{d1.name}}
        <ul *ngFor="let d2 of _dataList">
            <li *ngIf="d2.parent == d1.id">{{d2.name}}</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
</div>
```

- css from http://odyniec.net/articles/turning-lists-into-trees/
- angular from https://gist.github.com/arniebradfo/5cf89c362cc216df6fc1d9ca4d536b72
- js (how to convert flat array to tree) from me :D

### [Solution 1]=>

### JS

```
let xTree = [{
                "id": 5,
                "name": "First name",
                "parent": 0
            },
            ...
        ];
        let tree = [{
            id: 0,
            name: 'root',
            parent: null,
            childs: []
        }];
        let todoList = [];
        Converter();
        function FindParent(list, el) {
            if (list.length > 0) {
                let res = list.find(x => x.id === el.parent);
                if (res) {
                    return res;
                } else {
                    let _res = undefined;
                    list.forEach(xchild => {
                        _res = FindParent(xchild.childs, el);
                        if (res)
                            return _res;
                    });
                    return _res
                }
            } else {
                return undefined;
            }
        }

        function Converter() {
            todoList = xTree;
            for (let x = 0; x < 90; x++) {
                todoList.forEach(r => {
                    let parent = FindParent(tree, r);
                    if (parent) {
                        if (!parent.childs) {
                            parent.childs = [];
                        }
                        parent.childs.push(r);
                        todoList = todoList.filter(el => el !== r);
                    }
                });
            }
        }
```

### html

```
<ul class="tree">
  <ng-template #recursiveList let-list="list">
    <li *ngFor="let item of list">
      {{item.name}}
      <ul *ngIf="item.childSet.length > 0">
        <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="recursiveList; context:{ list: item.data}"></ng-container>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ng-template>
  <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="recursiveList; context:{ list: data}"></ng-container>
</ul>
```

### css

```
ul.tree, ul.tree ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}
  ul.tree, ul.tree ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    background: url(/assets/vline.png) repeat-y;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
  }

    ul.tree ul {
      margin-left: 10px;
    }

    ul.tree li {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0 12px;
      line-height: 20px;
      background: url(/assets/node.png) no-repeat;
      color: #369;
      font-weight: bold;
    }

      ul.tree li:last-child {
        background: #fff url(/assets/lastnode.png) no-repeat;
      }
```

Answer (score 3):

you can have a recusive component, say the component called `TreeComponent`
and the template for `TreeComponent` will be like this

```
<div *ngFor="let item of dataList">
  <ul *ngIf="item.parent==parentId">
    <li>{{item.name}}
      <tree [parentId]="item.id" [dataList]="removeCurrentLevelItems(dataList,parentId)"></tree>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

check the [link here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jvaawg?file=src%2Fapp%2Ftree.component.html) for a live demo

Comment: hi, lucas, I can not find a way to do editing from the live demo link. Could you please help ?

Comment: @FengZhang it doesnt require permissions etc to do editing, you can try to fork to your one or check your browser console to see any errors