# How to create elements on the fly with angular?

Tags: angular

Using Vanilla or jQuery is pretty simple. But I've no clue in Angular.

I need to create a very custom tree view, so I've this...

```
<div class="tree">
  <div class="root">
    <div class="node 1" (click)="click()"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I'd like to insert node1 into the root and I need also to handle events.

Any clue about how to archive it ?

Comment: Are you try to make a recursive component? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37746516/use-component-in-itself-recursively-to-create-a-tree

Answer (score 2):

Use Renderer2 Service

```
const div = this.renderer2.createElement('div');
  const text = this.renderer2.createText('Hello world!');

  this.renderer2.appendChild(div, text);
  this.renderer2.appendChild(this.elem.nativeElement, div);


    this.renderer2.listen(this.elem.nativeElement, 'click', () => {
      alert('Click Event From dynamically created Div');
    });
```

Example:https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-renderer2-customevent

Answer (score 0):

The `node1` element has to be an Angular component itself. Then you will import it inside the `root` component and [create it dynamically](https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader). That component will have `@Output()` properties which you can access as a regular variable and subscribe to listen for it's events.