# Angular 8 component nested inside the same component event emitter

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic-framework, angular8

I have used the component nested inside the same component. when I change the checkbox in the parent component attached function called correctly and Event emitter is working fine but when I change the child checkbox attached function was fired but event emitter not available (as of my knowledge ever matter is not bind with child one). I want to emit the data when I change the checkbox in the child.

If anyone know the answer please help me to solve this problem. And what is the terminology for using component nested inside the same component?

**Thanking you**

This is stackblitz link https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-normal-tree
**(please check the console)**

**tree.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-tree',
  templateUrl: './tree.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./tree.component.css'],
})

export class TreeComponent {
  @Input() treeData: any;
  @Output() toggleEmitter: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();

  constructor() {}

  toggleChild(node) {
    console.log('from tree start');
    console.log(node);
    console.log('from tree end');
    this.toggleEmitter.emit(node);
    // if ('children' in node && node.children.length) {
    //   node.isExpand = !node.isExpand;
    // }
  }

  test(node, i) {
    node.parentIndex = i;
    console.log(node);
    // this.toggleEmitter.emit(node);
  }

  CBchangeEvent(node) {
    console.log(node);
    this.toggleEmitter.emit(node);
  }

}
```

**tree.component.html**

```
<ul *ngIf="treeData">
    <li *ngFor="let node of treeData;let i = index;">
        <button mat-icon-button="" mattreenodetoggle="" class="mat-icon-button" (click)="toggleChild(node)">
        <span class="mat-button-wrapper">
          <mat-icon class="mat-icon material-icons" role="img" aria-hidden="true"> 
            {{node.isExpand != 0 ? 'expand_more' : 'chevron_right'}} 
          </mat-icon>
        </span>
      </button>
        <mat-checkbox class="checklist-leaf-node" (change)="CBchangeEvent(node)">{{node.name}}</mat-checkbox>
        <app-tree *ngIf="node.isExpand" [treeData]="node.children" (toggleEmitter)="test(node,i)"></app-tree>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**tree.component.css**

```
ul {
    list-style-type: none !important;
}
```

**tree.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { TreeComponent } from './tree.component';
import {
  MatIconModule, MatCheckboxModule, MatFormFieldModule, MatButtonModule
} from '@angular/material';


@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    MatIconModule, 
    MatCheckboxModule, 
    MatFormFieldModule, 
    MatButtonModule
  ],
  declarations: [TreeComponent],
  exports: [TreeComponent]
})
export class TreeModule {
  static forRoot() {
    return {
      ngModule: TreeModule
    }
  }
}
```

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  myData = [
    {'id':1, 'name':'Main 1','isExpand':false,
     'children':[
       {'id':1, 'name':'Child 1', 'isExpand':false,
       'children':[
         {'id':2, 'name':'Test2','isExpand':false}
       ]
       }
     ] 
    },
    {
      'id':2, 'name':'Main 2','isExpand':false
    }
  ]

  test(node) {
    console.log('from app start');
    console.log(node);
    console.log('from app end');
    if ('children' in node && node.children.length) {
      node.isExpand = !node.isExpand;
    }
  }
}
```

**app.component.html**

```
<app-tree [treeData]='myData' (toggleEmitter)="test($event)"></app-tree>
```

**app.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { TreeModule } from './tree/tree.module';
import {
  MdToolbarModule,
  MdTabsModule,
  MdButtonModule,
  MdInputModule,
  MdDatepickerModule,
  MdNativeDateModule,
  MdCheckboxModule,
  MdRadioModule,
  NoConflictStyleCompatibilityMode
} from '@angular/material';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

@NgModule({
  imports:      [ BrowserModule, FormsModule, BrowserAnimationsModule, MdToolbarModule, MdTabsModule, MdButtonModule, MdInputModule, MdDatepickerModule, MdNativeDateModule, MdCheckboxModule, MdRadioModule, TreeModule, NoConflictStyleCompatibilityMode ],
  declarations: [ AppComponent ],
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: This might be related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37746516/use-component-in-itself-recursively-to-create-a-tree

Comment: @BerkKurkcuoglu This is not related to my question. Thank you

Comment: Hey @cfprabhu , you are using app-tree tag inside tree-component.html?
tree-component.html tag again attached to app-tree component.

won't that me making an infine recurring loop?

Comment: Oh I got its more like recursion building tree.

Comment: Hey  @cfprabhu you have commented out emit code in below function

test(node, i) {
    node.parentIndex = i;
    console.log(node);
    // this.toggleEmitter.emit(node);
  }

Comment: I am not seeing any node filed in tree.component.ts but you have used it in binding with its child.

Comment: Are You Saying node is empyt in test(node,i) function ???

Comment: If I check/uncheck the parent node checkbox I can emit that node to parent component. But If I check/uncheck the child node checkbox I can't emit that node from child to parent. (I know the technical reason why it's not emitting. But I need to achieve this with alternative way)

Comment: What do you mean by EventEmitter not available? what error are you facing

Comment: @AkhilSurapuram https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-normal-tree

Comment: @cfprabhu there are some wrong in recursion printing of code.
your test2 object in not getting printed in tree diagram.

Answer (score 0):

Event Emitter works in this way

> Parent passes Data to child

and

> Child Emits when to let know parent that Data has been - so that
>   parent can call its call back function

For child Knowing Parent has changed Date

> Here there is a data binding happening, just like how *ngif works 
>   when ever child check data it will always be latest data.

child component Input() variable will be in same state of variable which is passed on binding. Binding takes care of updating child UI - on change in state of binded varaibles

Comment: Yes, brother. I know the working concept. If you know any alternative way to achieve my goal let me know, please.

Answer (score 0):

instead of biding "test" you should bind "toggleChild" in child component.

change

```
<app-tree *ngIf="node.isExpand" [treeData]="node.children" (toggleEmitter)="test(node,i)"></app-tree>
```

to

```
<app-tree *ngIf="node.isExpand" [treeData]="node.children" (toggleEmitter)="toggleChild(node,i)"></app-tree>
```

Comment: No brother. it's wrong. Read my question again and check the checkbox

Comment: sorry, mybad.
so what you want is that when child node (e.g "child1" in your data) is toggled, event should be emitted with its value ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62093782/angular-8-component-nested-inside-the-same-component-event-emitter#comment109936129_62093782

Comment: in child you are binding the method with outer node value. (toggleEmitter)="test(node,i)"
can't you use $event here to get child node's value. something like (toggleEmitter)="test($event,i)" or test($event,node,i)?

Comment: i uncommented this line in test 
    this.toggleEmitter.emit(node); // line 30
and change the value from (toggleEmitter)="test(node,i)" to (toggleEmitter)="test($event,i)"
and was able to get the child node's value all the way till app component. if you don't want event to be emitted recursively then you can just leave that commented and do whatever you want to do with the child node value in test.