# Ionic 3+: how to navigate away from tabbed interface?

Tags: ionic-framework, navigation, ionic-tabs

My Ionic application first loads `LoginComponent` and when user successfully logs in, loads the main `TabsComponent` view which allows to switch between corresponding child views.

I am trying to make it load standalone `LoginComponent` without tabbed interface, and that is not working (once switched to `TabsComponent`, I cannot navigate away from tabbed interface).

I've tried following commands from under one of `TabsComponent` child views:

```
this.navCtrl.push(LoginComponent);      // Loads as a child view
this.navCtrl.setRoot(LoginComponent);   // Loads as a child view
this.navCtrl.popAll();                  // Error: navigation stack needs at least one root page
this.navCtrl.popTo(LoginComponent);     // Error: navigation stack needs at least one root page
```

I've went through Ionic documentation many times but I haven't found an answer to this question. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved this by injecting `TabsComponent` into it's child component, and then calling `this.navCtrl.setRoot(LoginComponent);` in a function inside `TabsComponent`:

```
// Child class of TabsComponent (loaded via tab click)
export class SettingsComponent {
    constructor(@Inject(forwardRef(() => TabsComponent)) private tabsComponent: TabsComponent) {
    }

    logOut(): void {
        this.tabsComponent.switchToLoginPage():
    }
}
```

And `switchToLoginPage` on `TabsComponent`:

```
import {Component, forwardRef, Inject} from '@angular/core';
// ... 
export class TabsComponent {
    constructor(private navCtrl: NavController) {
    }

    switchToLoginPage(): void {
        this.navCtrl.setRoot(LoginComponent);
    }
}
```

Based on this example: [How do I inject a parent component into a child component?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34540615/how-do-i-inject-a-parent-component-into-a-child-component)

If there is a better way I'd love to know about, otherwise hope this solution would help anyone.

Comment: A little way around having to do this is not using tabs and building your own 'tabs' looking interface. Use the footer to generate a similar layout to tabs/