# angular 2 - ngFor dynamic function

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-directives, angular2-components

I have a table component which takes an input JSON for the table format and another JSON for the data.  My question is, when my table is rendered with *ngFor, how do I call cellFunction?

My table format JSON:

```
tblFormat= [
        { headerTxt: 'Order ID', df: 'Order_ID', color: 'blue', cellFunction: 'testME1' },
        { headerTxt: 'Buyer Name', df: 'name', color: 'blue',cellFunction: 'testME2' }
]
```

My Component

```
import { Component, AfterViewInit, ViewChild, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'table-comp',
    template: `<table class="table table-hover">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th *ngFor="let h of tableInfo"  [style.color]="h.color">{{h.headerTxt}}</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor="let d of data">
            <td *ngFor="let c of tableInfo" [style.color]=" how do I? c.cellFunction()">
                {{d[c.df]}}
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
 </table>`
    inputs: ['data','tableInfo']
})

export class TableComp {
    tableInfo=[];
    data=[];
}
```

Comment: You want to call `c.cellFunction()` for assigning color using `[style.color]`?

Comment: What is cellFunction? Is it a function, or a string like shown?

Comment: `c[cellFunction]()` if you want to call `testME1()`

Comment: @baao I am assuming that the function is defined in his component. I don't assume the cells having Function as properties, although it can!

Comment: Haha. Yeah you're right. Would look really strange in the end... :-) @sabithpocker.

Answer (score 0):

Depends mainly on where `TestME1` and `TestME2` are defined. If it is the `TableComp`, you can try doing:

```
 <td *ngFor="let c of tblFormat" [style.color]="this[c.cellFunction]()">
```

If the functions are defined somewhere else, you just need to replace `this` with the Object where it is defined.

For example, you can have a service with all the color functions which you inject to the component:

```
class TableComp {
    constructor(public colorFunctions: ColorFunctions) {}
}
```

If you have a service like that, you can do:

```
<td *ngFor="let c of tblFormat" [style.color]="colorFunctions[c.cellFunction]()">
```

Actually, I have no idea what you are actually trying to do!

Comment: i'm trying to think how i would call it if the cellfunciton is defined in parent component

Comment: Why not move them to a service, that can be injected anywhere, is there any dependancy on parent on how the color values are resolved? Can you provide an example color resolver function with ParentComponet code?

Comment: Injecting parent to the child as a reference is not something anyone would recommend. [Read this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34540615/how-do-i-inject-a-parent-component-into-a-child-component)

Answer (score -1):

I have made this work, please check this link -> https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xwsq2a

Add `colorChose` method in component, and update template like this,

```
<td *ngFor="let c of tblFormat" [style.color]="colorChose(c.cellFunction)">
```

In component, in `colorChose` method

```
colorChose (param) {
  return this.executeFunctionByName(param, this);  
}
```

Create the `executeFunctionByName` method in the same component. This is used to call function when you know the function name as `string`.

```
executeFunctionByName(functionName, context /*, args */) {
  var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 2);
  var namespaces = functionName.split(".");
  var func = namespaces.pop();
  for(var i = 0; i < namespaces.length; i++) {
    context = context[namespaces[i]];
  }
  return context[func].apply(context, args);
}
```

I hope you have methods mentioned in `cellFunction`, in this case `testME1`, which returns color name,

```
testME1 () {
  return "red";
}
```

Hope it helps...

Comment: why would colorChose not just be "this[param].bind(this)()" instead of all that mess ;)

Comment: @patrick, yes, statement you have mentioned it works just fine. The method `executeFunctionByName` handles more scenarios, so I thought it's better to include that as whole.

Comment: what scenarios do you mean? i can not think of any, which isn't handled by the statement i've mentioned

Comment: @patrick, The one scenario is using `namespace` in function_name parameter for `executeFunctionByName`, i.e. `some_object.function_name` in parameter. i.e. 
 `this.executeFunctionByName(some_object.function_name, this); `. The function that should be executed in context of `some_object`. This function takes care of such scenarios, but this is not the case with respect to this question, though.