# Angular - Accessing Host properties from a child component

Tags: angular

I created a set of custom form components that renders the label, input and validations.

The component has a layout attribute that allow setting the position of the HTML elements (the component has defaults).

In most cases the layout for all components on a specific form is the same. I would like to be able to set the layout on the host component so the component will try taking it from the host component.

So instead of repeating layout like:

```
<div class='input-group'>
    <my-input type="text" id="name" label="Name" [layout] ="{'col_label':2, 'col_input':3,'col_validation':2}"></my-input>
    <my-input type="text" id="address" label="address" [layout] ="{'col_label':2, 'col_input':3,'col_validation':2}"></my-input>
    <my-input type="number" id="zip" label="zip" [layout] ="{'col_label':2, 'col_input':3,'col_validation':2}"></my-input>
</div>
```

I will have properties on my Form’s component

```
export class UserFormComponent {
    col_label=2;
    col_input=3;
    col_validation'=2;
.
.
.
}
```

And on the component I can query the host for the values (if exists). something like:

```
.
.
this._gridLabelColumn = parent.col_label;
this._gridInputColumn = parent.col_input;
.
.
```

This will make the html much shorter:

```
<div class='input-group'>
    <my-input type="text" id="name" label="Name"></my-input>
    <my-input type="text" id="address" label="address"></my-input>
    <my-input type="number" id="zip" label="zip"></my-input>
</div>
```

Please note that components can be hosted in many forms/components, so I really don't know what is the host type.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to communicate between parent and children using [service](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#parent-and-children-communicate-via-a-service) or [@ViewChild](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#parent-calls-an-viewchild). It is all described in guide urls that I pasted.

**EDIT:**
Check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34540842/5909692) but it depends on parent component type.

Other option is to use `@Input` and pass parent instance into each `my-input`.

Comment: @ViewChild is for the other direction, Parent to child, I need to access child to parent. communicating using a service is not an option as the controls will be used in many projects and code will be very clumsy.